# Is it possible to use OWASP ZAP in front of the webserver?

Tags: linux, owasp, zap

My question is, Can I use OWASP ZAP as a front-end (in front of my webserver), to scan all the quests made?

I want to keep track of how the requests are sent and whenever a user exploits a vulnerability.

I was thinking about setting owasp at port 80 and redirect all the traffic to port 8080 (wenserver), but I don't know if thats possible.

Extra info - I use Linux terminal only, so I think I will have to use Zap pythonApi.. isnt it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I just discovered AWS WAF, which is what I wanted